# Matching Regexes and adding corresponding labels in df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having some issues regarding regexes matching in my dataframe. I want to create an additional column in the dataframe that matches the right RegexLabel if the String of column y contains substrings of the RegexGroceries | RegexFurniture

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
# Dataframe
data = {'X': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Y': ["supermarkt", "ikea", "albert heijn", "vloer"]}  

# Regexes
RegexGroceries = ["boni","supermarkt","nutri","company lukic","albert heijn"] 
RegexFurniture = ["ikea","meubel","tuin","tapijt","carpet","auping","bed"]

# Labels and categories
RegexCategories = [RegexGroceries, RegexFurniture]
RegexLabels = ["Groceries", "Furniture"]

# Apply labels for all regexes
counter = 0
for i in RegexCategories:
    for j in i:
        data['RegexCategory'] = np.where(data['y'].str.contains(j), RegexLabels[0 + counter], "None")
    counter = counter + 1
```

Somehow my df[RegexCategory] only returns None. Can anyone help me?

My output needs to look like this:

| X | Y | RegexCategory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | supermarkt | Groceries |
| 2 | ikea | Furniture |
| 3 | albert heijn | Groceries |
| 4 | vloer | None |

|

Answer (score 0):

What you call regexes are in fact lists of strings which means you can use `isin()` for matching, ie.:

```
# Dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Y': ["supermarkt", "ikea", "albert heijn", "vloer"]})

# Categories
Groceries = ["boni","supermarkt","nutri","company lukic","albert heijn"]
Furniture = ["ikea","meubel","tuin","tapijt","carpet","auping","bed"]

data['Category'] = None
data.loc[data.Y.isin(Groceries), 'Category'] = 'Groceries'
data.loc[data.Y.isin(Furniture), 'Category'] = 'Furniture'
```

Result:

```
In [72]: data
Out[72]: 
   X             Y   Category
0  1    supermarkt  Groceries
1  2          ikea  Furniture
2  3  albert heijn  Groceries
3  4         vloer       None
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, i want this to be a scalable solution for in the future (e.g. 60 categories and labels). So for me a problem arises when matching the right category to the right label

Comment: If you are planning to have more categories and labels you can still use lists of string and ```isin()``` matching. It is also possible to solve this using regular expressions, but you would need to design the matching patters very carefully, ie. carpet is in Furniture, car and pet are not, but both match parts of the carpet string, so string boundaries have to be included in the pattern to avoid false assignments, but then the regex matching process would not be any different from ```isin()```.